# What is too many sandboxed challenges?

Tags: discussion, support

I am very enthusiastic about this community (but I am very very young here) and I really want to contribute with new challenges.

On the other hand, I don't want to "clog" the sandbox with challenges I propose. Would you say there is a limit on the number of challenges I post on the sandbox? Or would you say that, as long as they are valid and legitimate challenges, I am welcome to post them in the sandbox? Or would you say something else?

I am writing mainly in view of [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13608/should-every-question-be-sandboxed) meta question. I want to get a better feel for what this community enjoys and appreciates. When I get the hang of it, I trust in my intelligence to be able to post good challenges without having to sandbox all of them.

Comment: If you are writing in light of my question you might want to look at the answers there too.  They give a good impression of what the community feels and are relevant to your question.

Answer (score 15):

## Don't worry about clogging the sandbox

In fact, thank you for using it — I wish every new contributor did so!

Every once in a while, we have created a new sandbox because the old one simply got too full. You'll find that many experienced users have several unfinished ideas lingering there too.

When you post your challenge to the main site:

1. Edit the sandbox post to say only `[Challenge title](link to main challenge)`
2. Delete the sandbox post

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Which one is the most recent sandbox, then?

Comment: I wasn't even aware there were more sandboxes.

Comment: @RGS The one linked to from the info box. Don't worry, even if you happen to stumble upon an old one, it'll have been edited to make that clear, and also locked down to prevent further answers.